How can i disable autofocus in react-select?
I have a selectbox from "react-select" library. I Need multi select without wrapping as i showed in sandbox. But whenever i remove one of chips or click input, Its autofocus to last one which i don't want. It need always stay in start. How can i do it ? Thanks for helps.
Sandbox : https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-select-blur-onchange-forked-5lt4y5?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A15%2C31
I tried do it with flexbox justify-content start etc. but it doesn't worked on me.

There is this nice function called scrollIntoView. All you have to do is to figure out how to get a reference to an option you want to be visible. When you have it, you use it like that:
optionRef.scrollIntoView()

Additionally, if you really insist on not wrapping, what you could do is adding a scroll to the input, because now there is no way to even see some of the selected options if they exceed the width of the input:
        valueContainer: (styles) => ({
          ...styles,
          flexWrap: "nowrap",
          overflow: "auto",
          minHeight: 40,
        }),

overflow: 'auto' + minHeight to compensate for it.
